# To what extent is a possible to write a web application with WPF and are there any advantages of doing so over using ASP.NET / MVC?

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc

I know that it's possible to use WPF for web development but are there any circumstances in which it would be better to use WPF? Or is it more common practice to ASP.NET Forms/MVC?

Comment: HTML5 is catching up, so MVC is usually the way to go for new projects. WPF (Silverlight?) was introduced when the browser-client interaction was much less defined.

Comment: I know MVC is usually the way to go, i'm asking if there are any circumstances to which WPF would be more suited

Comment: And I explained there are hardly any cases you'd use WPF (do you mean Silverlight?) anymore, because HTML 5 has replaced it. You can do a comparison yourself.

Comment: @codecaster except if you need to create a Windows application, where HTML makes no sense. HTML does not replace XAML in any way. it does not have DataBinding.

Comment: @Highcore I think you're missing the point. OP is talking about using WPF for **web development**. That is possible, with the subset of WPF called Silverlight, but the *need* to use it (or alternatives like Flash or ActiveX) has declined due to the development of HTML 5 and corresponding JavaScript functionality and libraries.

Comment: @CodeCaster There is no such thing as `WPF for Web development`. See my answer. WPF is a Windows Client technology, it has nothing to do with web. Silverlight is not WPF. and if you're going to state that HTML has replaced anything, that would be silverlight NOT WPF. WPF is still the preferred technology for Windows Desktop development.

Comment: @Highcore that is why I asked OP twice whether he meant Silverlight. OP is clearly not talking about Windows applications. Again, Silverlight, a subset of WPF, was created to deliver stuff through the browser that HTML could not or barely do at the time. But now it can, so Silverlight is considered obsolete, so the answer is: no, don't use Silverlight (if that is what you mean with WPF) as it offers little over HTML+JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that it's possible to use WPF for web development

Wrong. WPF is part of the .Net Framework. It is a Windows Client technology that requires the target computer to have the .Net Framework installed in order to run.

*Web applications* consist of a **Web Server** delivering **Web Content** (**HTML** `[+Javascript+CSS]`)  to a **Web Client** (Browser).

WPF has nothing to do with that. It does **not** produce HTML or any other Web content and it is **not** a *Server Side* technology.

Bottom line:

- Use Web technologies (A server side technology that outputs `HTML` (such as `ASP.Net MVC`)) if you need to create a Web Application.
- Use WPF if you need to create a rich, highly interactive Windows Desktop application.
- Use WinRT XAML (similar to WPF) if you need to create a rich, highly interactive Windows "Metro Style" application.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @HighCore said, it's possible to use technology similar to WPF in a web environment. For example, Silverlight uses XAML markup. It's kind of similar to a Java applet if you're familiar with those. Silverlight is particularly handy for doing something that requires a lot of graphics or media in the browser, but it's not as full featured as WPF. In addition, you have to hope that the user has a Silverlight plugin which isn't available on all platforms. For example, Linux and mobile have limited or no Silverlight capability.

You could develop a WPF application and deliver it as a [ClickOnce application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce). You're pretty much limited to Windows targets.

If you're trying to develop a website, then stick to ASP.NET Web Forms or MVC or some other server side technology that serves HTML to browsers, as HighCore said.